# How to show error messages in corresponding cell in xeditable table

Tags: x-editable

I have found below code to show error message in `xeditable table`

```
$scope.editableform.$setError('name', 'unknown error');
```

But this code places error message in all cells in the column `name`.
I want the error message be placed on particular cell which is wrong. How to implement it?

Comment: use the error option and target the element where you wanted to display the message.

Comment: claudios ,can u pls write the code. I hv used above code, but it display error msg in all the cells in the column named 'name'.